# NoMethodError in Polls#new -- undefined method `polls' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

Hello I have to develop a GoogleForm like application i already developed Forms/Questions/Answers and now i have to make my forms 'answerable' so I created a model Poll (a Form has_many polls and a poll belongs to a form). I Have this mistake https://projet.../formulaires/131/polls/new  and I don't understand how to handle it .

My routes.rb :

```
  resources :formulaires do
     resources :polls
  end
```

My polls_controller :

```
def index
    @polls = @formulaire.polls.order("created_at DESC")
end

def show
end

def new
  @poll = Poll.new

end

def create
    @poll = @formulaire.poll.new(poll_params)
    @polls = @formulaire.polls.order("created_at DESC")

    if @poll.save
       redirect_to formulaire_polls_path(@formulaire)
    end
end

def poll_params
  params.require(:poll).permit(:formulaire_id, :question_id, :answer_id, :nom) 
end

end
```

And my polls/_form view to test it :

```
  <%= form_for([@formulaire, @formulaire.polls.new]) do |f| %>

<h2> Test</h2>
  <%= f.label :nom %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@polls = @formulaire.polls.order("created_at DESC")
```

Where did you define `@formulaire`?

You need to do...

```
@formulaire = Formulaire.find(params[:formulaire_id]
@polls = @formulaire.polls.order("created_at DESC")
```

You need to have the same line in your `create` method.  In fact, it may make sense to assign `@formulaire` in a before_action that you call before all the CRUD methods.

Comment: Thank you @SteveTurczyn i added it in my 'new' method